# Is there a way to vectorize sprintf() in an octave script?

Tags: octave

Is there a way in Octave to vectorize sprintf()?

See the example, below. The iterative branch works as expected. When I set vectorize_sprintf=1, I don't get the desired effect. Instead of filling the LABELS cell array with one string per cell, all of the strings are concatenated into the first cell of LABELS and the remaining cells are left empty.

Is there a good way to vectorize number to string processing?

```
%%
%% Graph e^x and ln()
%%

top=8;                          %% highest power to graph
pow_vec = [0:top]';
ex_vec = e .^ pow_vec;
ln_vec = log(ex_vec);

LABELS=cell(size(ex_vec));      %% Pre-allocate cell matrix
vectorize_sprintf=1;

if ( vectorize_sprintf )
  %% Vectorize attempt at sprintf is BROKEN
  LABELS=sprintf("%d = log2(%d)\n",ln_vec,ex_vec)
else
  %% Iterate for sprintf WORKS
  counter=1;
  for i = pow_vec'
    LABELS(counter++) = sprintf("e^%d=%d\nln(%d)=%d",pow_vec(counter),ex_vec(counter) ,ex_vec(counter) ,ln_vec(counter));
  endfor
endif

figure(1);                      %% Graph e^x
hold on;
plot(ln_vec, ex_vec, "r-");     %% solid red line segments
plot(ln_vec, ex_vec, "rx");     %% markers on the datapoints
text(ln_vec, ex_vec, LABELS);

figure(2);                      %% Graph ln()
hold on;
plot(ex_vec, ln_vec, "r-");     %% solid red line segments
plot(ex_vec, ln_vec, "rx");     %% markers on the datapoints
text(ex_vec, ln_vec, LABELS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vectorization attempt is not filling the first cell of `LABELS`, it is actually converting it to a char array (take a look at `whos LABELS`). I think sprintf always returns a single string only. Since you're using `\n`, maybe you could use `strsplit` to get a cell array.

```
ex_vec = e .^ [0:8];
ln_vec = log(ex_vec);

LABELS = strsplit (sprintf ("%.0f = log2(%.4f)\n", [ln_vec; ex_vec]), "\n")(1:end-1)
```

I have made the following changes to what you had before:

1. don't transpose the [0:8] so you get a row, and you don't have to transpose it again when generating a matrix for sprintf
2. replaced the `%d` by `%.0f` and `%.4f`. It's specially important the %.0f because `log (e^8) = 8.0000` but what is used in the string is `fix (log (e^8))` which is 7. Alternatively, you can round `ln_vec`

Comment: Thanks carandraug, the values are shifted around in an annoying fashion: ex_vec = e .^ [0:2]'; LABELS = strsplit (sprintf ("log(%f) = %f\n", ex_vec, ln_vec), "\n")(1:end-1) ---Gives surprising result--- ex_vec =

   1.0000
   2.7183
   7.3891

ln_vec =

   0
   1
   2

LABELS = 
{
  [1,1] = log(1.000000) = 2.718282
  [1,2] = log(7.389056) = 0.000000
  [1,3] = log(1.000000) = 2.000000
}
Why are they shifted?

Comment: The Octave manual says, "...vectorization also allows for better optimization... The ultimate goal [of vectorization] is to make use of your hardware's vector instructions if possible or to perform other optimizations in software." From an optimization perspective, jamming everything into one string and splitting it back out with strsplit() is a worse solution than iterating over the elements of the vector. Is there a better solution.

Comment: @JeffTaylor on the other hand, a one line gets interpreted only once. Having a for loop, because the way Octave interpreter works, will be interpreted many times (this may change in the future once JIT is finished stops being experimental). Give it a try with a long enough loop and take the conclusions for yourself.

Comment: @JeffTaylor you may be able to do its with `cellfun` which might be closer to your definition of vectorization but I doubt you'll get much better performance. Only some functions get a performance increase with `cellfun` and I don't think `sprintf` is one of them.